# Execute code from ROM, Stack and Variable in RAM

Tags: gcc, embedded, executable, rom

I have a small application and on our board we have ROM. I would like for this program to be executed from the ROM while having variables and stack in RAM.

I understand I need to place my .text segment, followed by my .data segment in ROM. And then at startup have some code that initialize the hardware, then copies the .data to RAM, initialize the .bss to 0 and initializes the stack.

My problem is I'm not really sure of which technique to use for this.
Can anyone shed some light on how I could achieve this ?

For information, I'm using gcc with the sparc-elf target.

Comment: there are many examples out there and a number crt0.S files that do this.  The common practices for gnu tools is to have some labels/variables in the linker script around the .data segment declarations.  that tells the bootstrap code where the .data segment is in rom and it simply copies it to ram, again using a linker script variable to know where .data is in ram.  bss same deal, linker variables the boostrap assembler uses to zero some amount of ram.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the linker command file. It allows you to locate your sections (.data, .bss, .text) to specific memory locations such as RAM or ROM. Im assuming your asking for an embedded application with a BSP startup, not the c-runtime startup).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out. And yes it's for an embedded application